# How do I put to div elements each in a side of a container without floats?

Tags: css

I have this CSS:

```
div#element1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}
div#element2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}
```

How do I do this without float? I've tried with `display: inline-block;` but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Can you provide some relevant HTML demonstrating what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Why do you want to do it without floats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is an option:**

```
<html>
<style>
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
div #element1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}
div #element2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
<body>
<div>
    <div id="element1">element1</div>
    <div id="element2">element2</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Or just:

```
div #element1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
div #element2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `display: inline-block;` like you said, 
but also add `white-space: nowrap;` on the parent of `#element1 & #element2`